# spark elastic search throwing 403 forbidden error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

When I tried to connect the elasticsearch from spark using basic authentication to create a new index got below error.

Error from elastic search is not giving full error information to debug more

```
 org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: [HEAD] on [devl_test_index] failed; server[https://<elasticServerHost>:9200] returned [403|Forbidden:]
            at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:477)
            at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.executeNotFoundAllowed(RestClient.java:447)
            at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.exists(RestClient.java:539)
            at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.indexExists(RestClient.java:534)
            at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.touch(RestClient.java:545)
            at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.touch(RestRepository.java:364)
            at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.initSingleIndex(RestService.java:660)
            at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:636)
            at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:65)
            at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:101)
            at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:101)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Code used to connect:

```
Sbt dependency: "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "7.5.0"

import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

 val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkJDBC")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("spark.es.port","9200")
    .config("spark.es.nodes", "<elasticServerHost>")
    .config("spark.es.nodes.wan.only","true")
    .config("spark.es.net.ssl","true")
    .config("spark.es.net.http.auth.user","USERNAME")
    .config("spark.es.net.http.auth.pass","PASSWRD")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.sql("select * from employee")

df.saveToEs("devl_test_index")
```

Answer (score 5):

This error will be thrown from elastic search server when the user tries to access the index instead of assigned group.

In my case, my user group has access to the index which starts with employee* but I tried to access the index starts with devl*

If you run the spark in debug mode you will get the actual error stack trace with more info like below:

```
20/02/19 10:38:57 DEBUG wire.header: << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
20/02/19 10:38:57 DEBUG wire.header: << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
20/02/19 10:38:57 DEBUG wire.header: << "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
20/02/19 10:38:57 DEBUG wire.header: << "content-length: 259[\r][\n]"
20/02/19 10:38:57 DEBUG wire.header: << "[\r][\n]"
20/02/19 10:38:57 DEBUG wire.content: << "{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:admin/aliases/get] is unauthorized for user [rdsuser]"}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [indices:admin/aliases/get] is unauthorized for user [USERNAME]"},"status":403}"
20/02/19 10:38:57 DEBUG sql.EsDataFrameWriter: Provided index name [devl_test_index] is not an alias. Reason: [org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: security_exception: action [indices:admin/aliases/get] is unauthorized for user [USERNAME]
null]
```

Internally spark will check for the existence of index name before it creates a new one. In this process, it will hit the alias API /_all/_alias/devl_test_index

Error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "action [indices:admin/aliases/get] is unauthorized for user [USERNAME]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "action [indices:admin/aliases/get] is unauthorized for user [USERNAME]"
    },
    "status": 403
}
```